# Call to a member function getItemsCount() on a non-object in view.pthml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Fatal error: Call to a member function getItemsCount() on a non-object

in \app\design\frontend\default\jorg\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml on line 49

can any help on this.

Magento 1.7

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
        <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
        <dl id="narrow-by-list">
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>              
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>             
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: is this any thing related to attributes.

Comment: Can you tell me things you have customized? a short overview.

Comment: I have deleted some of the attributes

Comment: I have deleted attributes based on which filter was done and created same attribute again with same name, their also exist product related to the deleted attribute.

Comment: Is deleted attribute keeping reference or something ? Are they having any relevance now ?

Comment: Paste yout .html file

Comment: have you flushed your cache etc

Comment: Have you ever deleted anything directly from your database, not through Magento's built in coding? My suggestion is to take your skin and design files over to a clean install on a local LAMP/WAMP and test if it occurs there. Basically, it's not pulling up any layered navigation filters (if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>) the $_filter is not an object. So it is not getting any objects when it searches for the filters.

Comment: Also, you should check all your product attributes, make sure the attributes you want to use for layered navigation have "Use in Layered Navigation" set to Yes.

Comment: flush the cache first and reindex and that will probably fix it

Comment: Which data is returned if you do `var_dump($_filters)`?
I think that your block type is wrong, it must be catalog/layer_view and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the posible cause of error

1. put var_dump(get_class($this));exit; in the .phtml in the first line => then go to class and show the method getFilters()
2. Show the type of object return the method getFilters()

   1. Can be return $this -> is in the current class
   2. Or can be another type of object -> go to the object type
3. Search the method getItemsCount() in the object class of the second step. Show the return of this method.

Are you active Developer Mode? This can show you more information in case of errors.